# Bet sizes in Limit Texas Hold'em in cases of a players all-in

Tags: texas-hold-em, all-in

I wonder what the valid bet sizes are in Limit Texas Hold'em in case of a players all-in.
Consider the following example:
5/10 Limit Texas Hold'em game.
Three players A, B and C. On the flop Player A bets 5, Player B goes all-in with 7. 
What are the valid amounts of chips that player C can put on the table? 
Is 7 a valid call?
What about 10, 12, 15?

This question is not about how side pots work! It is about what happens to the bet size in Limit Hold'em in case a players all-in does not match the bet-size. It is NOT a duplicate of the question about side pots!

Answer (score 0):

If you play 5/10 Limit the smallest chip is 5, so a player will never have 7 Chips. Since 7 is lower than the bigblind, it's invalid. You can always call the next bigblind, so 10,20,30... but not 15 or 12. I guess you made a small mistake there. Player A can't bet 5 in a 10chips bigblind game.

Comment: 10 is not the big blind, 5 is the big blind. 5 is also the bet-size in the first two rounds. 10 is the bet size on turn and river. This is the naming convention for Limit Hold'em. It can indeed happen that a player has less chips than the big blind or the small blind (at least I saw this online and I don't see any reason why this is invalid in the first place).
The question remains: What are the proper calls/raises in case a players all-in does not match the bet size?

Comment: If 5 is the bigblind, what is the small blind ? 2 and a half ? If there is a cashgame, not Sit and go, you can't buy in with strange number like 100 euro and 2 cents if blinds are 5/10 (small/big) you can only buy in with a number of bigblinds. When it comes to a split pot with 3 persons including a folded small blind you can have 25 split into 3 which resulsts in a 12,5 to both yea sorry agree strange numbers can appear out of this. but normally someone gifts the coin to the dealer or next player ;)

Comment: @RayofCommand, at pokerstars you can buyin with any amount between the min and max set by their rules. So if buyin min. is $3.50 and max $10, you can buyin with $7.44 or $9.99. Or is there a difference between limit holdem and no limit with the bet ranges? Because the rules in nolimit are that you've to min bet the BB and reraise at least as big as the raise before.